# App Store rejection due to insufficient location usage explanation in Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, location, app-store-connect, location-services

I recently submitted my Expo app to the App Store and it got rejected with the reason stating, "We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the location, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the location in the purpose string."

I have already ensured that my app.json contains the necessary keys for location permissions as follows:

```
    "infoPList": {
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [
            {
                "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
                    "com.googleusercontent.apps.XXX-XXX"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "UIRequiresFullScreen": true,
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "XXX Message",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "XXX Message",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "XXX Message",
        "NSLocationUsageDescription": "XXX Message",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "XXX Message."
    },
    "buildNumber": "27",
    "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

```
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "XXX Message"
        }
      ],
```

Where "XXX Message" represents the actual explanation of why my app requires access to the user's location. Despite this, the rejection still occurred.

I am using Expo version "~49.0.6" and React Native version "0.72.6".

What could be the reason for this rejection, and how can I ensure that my app complies with the App Store guidelines regarding location access explanations? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Update:** The message I defined is not being displayed! It just says: "Allow XXX to access your location". While the strings I defined are pretty descriptive!

Answer (score 1):

you should try submitting app with proper explanation of why app uses location permission in purpose string like **$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to always/background access your current location to get nearby friends.**

Comment: I have already provided the explanation in all 3 keys!

Comment: I think that explanation is not clear as user or not relevant.

Comment: The string which I defined is not appearing, It just says: "Allow XXX to access your location". I think variables in infoPList are not being detected!

Comment: If you are using expo-location package see https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/.

Comment: Because infoPlist is modified by config plugin of this package with eas build.

Comment: Plugin is already included, I have updated my question.

Comment: You should try to add also `locationWhenInUsePermission` in plugin configuration `expo-location`.